# How to pass "conditional" default value by checking its value in the Vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

Component

```js
props: {
  image: {
    type: String,
    default() {
       return this.defaultImage
    }
  }
},

computed: {
  defaultImage() {
     return this.$config.baseUrl + '/images/default.jpg'
  }
},
```

Using the above component, when prop-image is not present, the component returns default-image successfully.

```html
<image-uplaoder />
```

But I want to achieve, if I pass the value for prop-image and the value is null, it should still return default-image. Currently, it returns nothing.

```html
<image-uplaoder :image="data.image" />
```

**Tried** (can't we do something like) as follows?

```js
computed: {
  defaultImage(value) {
    if(!value || value === null) {
      return this.$config.baseUrl + '/images/default.jpg'
    }
  }
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the prop's `default()` option, the computed property should contain the logic to use a default value:

```js
// ImageUploader.vue
export default {
  props: {
    image: String,
  },
  computed: {
    imgUrl() {
      return this.image || (this.$config.baseUrl + '/images/default.jpg')
    }
  }
}
```

Then bind the computed property to your `<img>.src`:

```html
<img :src="imgUrl">
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-default-computed-prop?file=components/ImageUploader.vue)